# How to understand this proof on minmax theorem

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, game-theory

Please check out the piece.

My question:

1. Why it's using the assumption 0∈C or 0∉C, why such kind of assumption make sense?
2. What's the name of this lemma

Thanks[image]

Comment: Hard to guess what you are looking at, but Farka's lemma might be a possibility. It is one of many theorems of the alternative.

Comment: Personally I find such results much more intuitive in the setting of convex cones and the separation theorem.